# Three elements in one row in table

Tags: html, css

I want to put hr between two elements in my table. I am creating mailing templemate. How can I put it in one row? Here's code:

```css
 body {
  width: 100% !important;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 100%;
}

#outlook a {
  padding: 0;
}

.ExternalClass {
  width: 100%;
}

.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
  line-height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tablereset {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 640px !important;
  line-height: 100% !important
}

.button {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.devicewidthsocial {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  max-width: 100%!important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}

td.boxesfont {
  font-size: 17px !important;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important
}

td[class*=font-resize] {
  font-size: 140%!important
}

td[style*="Roboto"] {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important
}

td[style*="Open Sans"] {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif !important
}

@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  a[href="tel"],
  a[href="sms"] {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
  }
  tr.removemobile {
    display: none;
  }
  td[class*=threecolumnphoto] {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  table[class*=button] {
    float: none;
  }
  table.removemobile {
    display: none;
  }
  table.tablereset {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 440px !important;
    line-height: 100% !important
  }
  table[class*=devicewidth] {
    width: 440px!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    float: none!important;
    display: table!important;
  }
  table[class*=devicewidthinner] {
    width: 400px!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    float: none!important;
  }
  table[class*=devicewidthinner3] {
    width: 173px!important;
    float: none!important;
  }
  img[class*=logoImg] {
    width: 110px!important;
    height: auto!important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:479px) {
  table.removemobile {
    display: none;
  }
  table[class*=tablereset] {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 280px !important;
    line-height: 100% !important
  }
  img[class*=logoImg] {
    width: 100px!important;
    height: auto!important;
  }
  td[class*=threecolumnphoto] {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  table[class*=devicewidthright] {
    width: 160px!important;
  }
  table[class*=devicewidth] {
    width: 280px!important;
    float: none!important;
    display: table!important;
  }
  table[class*=devicewidthinner] {
    width: 240px!important;
    float: none!important;
  }
  table[class*=devicewidthinner3] {
    width: 173px!important;
    float: none!important;
  }
  table[class*=button] {
    float: none!important;
  }
  table[class*=button] td,
  table[class*=button] td a {
    font-size: 12px!important;
  }
  td[class*=oswaldfont] {
    font-size: large!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0; padding:0">
  <div>
    <table class="tablereset" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td width="640">
          <table class="devicewidth" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px" height="58" width="640">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p style="text-align: center">xyz</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px" height="18" width="640">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="640" align="center">
                <table class="devicewidthinner" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="350">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px; color:#b2b2b2;line-height: 18px;text-align: center;">
                      Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="40" width="640"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- pierwsza dwójka -->
    <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="tablereset" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td width="640">
          <table class="devicewidth" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="640" style="margin:0 auto;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
              <td width="640" align="center">
                <table class="devicewidthinner" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="317">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="640">
                      <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="devicewidthinner" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="270">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="640" height="26">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300;">lorem ipsum</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td width="640" align="left" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: 300; font-size: 20px;line-height:24px; color: #606060; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;">lorem ipsum </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="640" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left">
                            <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300; color: #606060;">Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis.</td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="640" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="devicewidthinner" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="10">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="10">
                      <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="devicewidthinner" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="10">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="10" height="26">
                            <hr style="
                border:none;border-left:1px solid hsla(200, 10%, 50%,100);height:20px;width:1px; 
                ">
                          </td>
                        </tr>

                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="devicewidthinner" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="640" align="center">
                      <table class="devicewidthinner" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="317">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" width="640">
                            <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="devicewidthinner" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="270">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" height="26">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300;">lorem ipsum
                                  <span style="color: red;text-decoration: line-through;">
                 <span style="color: #606060; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">
                  100
                 </span>
                                  </span>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" align="left" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: 300; font-size: 14px;line-height:24px;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">lorem ipsum </span><span style="color: #e4001b; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">lorem ipsum</span></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                  <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300;">
                                          <p>lorem ipsum:</p>
                                          <p><span>lorem ipsum: </span> lorem ipsum</p>
                                          <p><span>lorem ipsum: </span> lorem ipsum</p>
                                          <p><span>lorem ipsum: </span>lorem ipsum</p>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <table class="tablereset" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="1280">
                      <table class="devicewidth" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="640" style="margin:0 auto;">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="640" align="center">
                            <table class="devicewidthinner" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" width="1280">
                                  <a href="" style="font-family: Arial;color: #ffffff;font-size: 20px;background: #e4001b;padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;text-decoration: none;">Zobacz</a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nmsdcrc8/)..

Comment: Please add the code for the question in the question as well as the jsfiddle.

Comment: Where do you want to add hr tag?

Comment: between Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada and that right elements.

Comment: @Programmer you want to put it inside the td?

Comment: as a third element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many extra tables used in your code, although i have updated your code. Please check the updated snippet. Hope it is helpful to you.

```html
<body style="margin:0; padding:0">

  <table class="tablereset" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="640">
          <table class="devicewidth" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px" height="58" width="640">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p style="text-align: center">xyz</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px" height="18" width="640">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="640" align="center">
                  <table class="devicewidthinner" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="350">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px; color:#b2b2b2;line-height: 18px;text-align: center;">
                          Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis.
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="40" width="640"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- pierwsza dwójka -->
  <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="tablereset" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="640">
          <table class="devicewidth" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="640" style="margin:0 auto;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="640" align="center">
                  <table class="devicewidthinner" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" width="317">
                          <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="devicewidthinner" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="270">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" height="26">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300;">lorem ipsum</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" align="left" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: 300; font-size: 20px;line-height:24px; color: #606060; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;">lorem ipsum </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                  <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300; color: #606060;">Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis.</td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" width="1" valign="middle">
                            <span style="width:1px; height:20px; background:#000; display:block;"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="317" align="center">
                          <table class="devicewidthinner" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="317">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" width="640">
                                  <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="devicewidthinner" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="270">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td width="640" height="26">&nbsp;</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300;">lorem ipsum
                                          <span style="color: red;text-decoration: line-through;">
                     <span style="color: #606060; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">
                      100
                     </span>
                                          </span>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>

                                      <tr>
                                        <td width="640" align="left" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: 300; font-size: 14px;line-height:24px;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">lorem ipsum </span><span style="color: #e4001b; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">lorem ipsum</span></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="left">
                                          <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300;">
                                                  <p>lorem ipsum:</p>
                                                  <p><span>lorem ipsum: </span> lorem ipsum</p>
                                                  <p><span>lorem ipsum: </span> lorem ipsum</p>
                                                  <p><span>lorem ipsum: </span>lorem ipsum</p>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td width="640" height="10"></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>



                  <table class="tablereset" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="1280">
                          <table class="devicewidth" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="640" style="margin:0 auto;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td width="640" align="center">
                                  <table class="devicewidthinner" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" width="1280">
                                          <a href="" style="font-family: Arial;color: #ffffff;font-size: 20px;background: #e4001b;padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;">Zobacz</a>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>


        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: how to set height of that element?

Comment: Instead if using tables i converted three tables into `td` inside a single table due to which the height of `TD` with background increases to height of the `TD` that as more content. In that case you can simply add height to `td` in which background is defined. And you can align that border to middle using `align="middle"` in the specific td

Comment: I do not know understand. That line should be 20px height

Comment: Please check now if that seems helpful to you

Answer (score -1):

**A line created with `<hr>` is (always) horizontal.**

BUT, you can simply add a right border at the left column or a left border at the right column of the table.

Your css could look like this:

```
table tr td:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

So every first cell in a row, gets a right border. To ensure you don't have gaps between rows you may also want to add the following attributes to your table:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```